# What is the difference between 'Range.Parent' and 'Range.Worksheet' in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, properties, worksheet

The `.Parent` and `.Worksheet` properties, when used with a range, seem to reference to the same worksheet object where `Range` is located.

For example, both of these lines return the same value:

```
Debug.Print Selection.Parent.Name
Debug.Print Selection.Worksheet.Name
```

Is there a difference between the two?  Are there advantages/disadvantages to each method?

Comment: You would have to test all of the methods and properties native to the [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel) through .Parent to proof it but I would assume they are interchangeable; i.e. .Parent takes on all properties and methods of whatever it refers to.

Comment: For a lot of operations (loops) using `Selection.Parent` will be slower because Excel needs to determine what collection the `Selection` belongs to: `Charts`, `Names`, `Sheets`, `Styles`, `TableStyles`, `Windows`, `Worksheets`, `XmlNamespaces`. With `Selection.Worksheet` it goes directly to the `Worksheets` collection

Comment: The only difference I can think of is when you use `With`, IntelliSense cannot pick up any object's Parent. All kinds of objects top Parent is the **Application**, including it self interestingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can guarantee `Selection` is always part of a Worksheet, it's not said that `Selection.Parent.Name` will yield the same result as `Selection.Worksheet.Name`. If it's "in" other types of objects (charts or graphics, for example) the result could be quite different - you'd need to do some testing.

So, `Selection.Worksheet.Name` is more exact (and, as someone has pointed out in Comments, potentially faster in execution). But if you can't guarantee `Selection` is going to reference a `Worksheet` it can trigger an error or yield an unexpected result.

Comment: If the user selects an Excel chart then `TypeName(Selection)` is `ChartArea`.  `TypeName(Selection.Parent)` is `Chart`.  `TypeName(Selection.Parent.Parent)` is `ChartObject` and finally, `TypeName(Selection.Parent.Parent.Parent)` is `Worksheet`.